# vTune 2022.2 fails to load PDB symbols for .NET 6 console application

Tags: c#, .net, intel-vtune

I am attempting to use Intel vTune to profile a .NET 6 Console application. I am following the example from the [Intel website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-cookbook/top/configuration-recipes/profiling-a-net-core-application.html).

You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/matthewcrews/vTuneTestApp).

I have vTune 2022.2 installed and I running on Windows 10 Pro Version 21H2 Build 19044.1706

I updated the default `.csproj` file to have it build symbols in release mode:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I have vTune targeting the `dotnet.exe` executable as the target application and for the command line argument I give it is the location of the `vTuneTestApp.dll`.

[image: Launch Application Settings]

I also added the directory where the PDBs are located in the Binary/Symbol Search.
[image: Binary/Symbol Search Settings]

When I run the "Performance Snapshot" profiling I get the following feedback in the Collection Log.

```
Cannot locate file "C:\source\vTuneTestApp\bin\Release\net6.0\vTuneTestApp.dll".
"C:\source\vTuneTestApp\bin\Release\net6.0\vTuneTestApp.dll" does not have code
of the expected architecture. Make sure to specify the correct path to the file
in the Binary/Symbol Search list of directories.
```

[image: Collection Log output]

What am I doing wrong? I followed the example as closely as possible and it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

These are some warning messages only.
In general, the warning messages from your output are about system and VTune modules. You can ignore them if you are not interested in profiling system functions. Otherwise please see the "Debug Information for Windows* System Libraries" help topic in VTune help.

Regarding `Cannot locate file "C:\source\vTuneTestApp\bin\Release\net6.0\vTuneTestApp.dll". "C:\source\vTuneTestApp\bin\Release\net6.0\vTuneTestApp.dll" does not have code of the expected architecture. Make sure to specify the correct path to the file in the Binary/Symbol Search list of directories.`
It occurs when the VTune can’t find the shared dll libraries. Those libraries are compiled without debug symbols.

All the data would be collected even if the VTune throws this warning. You are free to ignore these warnings.

For more information please refer this link: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/troubleshooting/error-c...

Comment: The Debug symbols are generated. The PDBs are in the output directory and the output directory was added to the Binary/Symbols paths so saying "Those libraries are compiled without debug symbols" does not make sense to me. Is there some other way to compile? I have read the docs multiple times but it does not work which is why I asked this question.